# How to ssh into turtlebot?

Tags: turtlebot, ssh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got my computer for my turtlebot today, and I think (and hope!) I got it set up properly. However, while I was going through the tutorials, I encountered a problem with ssh-ing into my turtlebot. I typed "ssh turtlebot@turtlebot" into my terminal, but it says "ssh: Could not resolve hostname turtlebot: Name or service not known". Is there something I need to know about how to ssh into something? Do I need to type something else into the terminal?

-Parker Gibbons

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11030/how-to-ssh-into-turtlebot?/) by [ParkerGibbons](https://answers.ros.org/users/978/parkergibbons/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2011-08-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The computer that you're SSHing from needs to know what IP 'turtlebot' refers to is. Try finding the IP of the TurtleBot by running ifconfig in a terminal on the TurtleBot. Then, try:

```
ssh turtlebot@<IP>
```

If you are setting up a computer from scratch and are not using the official [TurtleBot iso](http://pr.willowgarage.com/downloads/turtlebot/turtlebot-amd64.iso), you may also need to install a server for ssh on your TurtleBot:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2011-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-08-30**:
I just checked it is in the ISO.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-08-28**:
I don't believe it's in the ISO at the moment.  TIcketed https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/trac/ticket/56

**Comment by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) on 2011-08-28**:
Easiest thing to do would be to run the second line from above to install it - it'll be much faster. I had thought the official distribution had the server installed, but it's possible that it's not included by default.

**Comment by [ParkerGibbons](https://answers.ros.org/users/978/parkergibbons/) on 2011-08-28**:
I was using the official iso, but I did not have an ssh server on the computer. So I may have not downloaded it properly. Can I re load it from the same USB stick?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are using your own IP adress as a target (127.0.0.1). You cant be the source and the target at the same time !
The idea of ssh is to log in from an other computer on the network. It should see turtlebot as a local IP, ideally something like 192.168.1.xx

---

Originally posted by [Jonathan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1107/jonathan/) with karma: 33 on 2011-09-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First of all check the ip-addresses of your systems.

You can do this with the command "ifconfig" at the terminal.
With this information, you can reach the remote system very easily.

ssh user@remote-ip-address

---

Originally posted by [Chrimo](https://answers.ros.org/users/361/chrimo/) with karma: 390 on 2011-09-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1